# select * FROM ALL_OBJECTS not showing me all packages but DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL will show me the DDL for missing objects

Tags: oracle

I am writing a program that populates a series of drill down combo boxes to allow me to drill into objects of an oracle schema.
The combo box levels are:

1. SCHEMA
2. Object TYPE
3. Object Name

select * FROM ALL_OBJECTS O WHERE O.OWNER = :SELECTED_SCHEMA and O.OBJECT_TYPE = :SELECTED_OBJECT_TYPE order by OBJECT_NAME

When Packages is the selected OBJECT_TYPE I am not getting all of the packages that are in the selected schema. However, TOAD for Oracle IS displaying all of the objects when I connect to the database.

Given that I connected within my program using the same ID as I connected to TOAD, I would expect TROAD to be using my credentials when querying the system tables.

What could TOAD be doing differently that might allow it to retrieve the full list of packages?

When I connect using a privileged account that has write access (this is for prod), the above query does return all of the packages and when I examine the GRANTS for the PACKAGE I see that my privileged account does has been granted EXECUTE rights.

I don't really understand why EXECUTE rights would need to be granted in order for me to be able to see that the package exists. In other vendor databases, I would expect there to be a privilege such as VIEW_SCHEMA that is granted to a user for an object. I would have expected d that I would have complete visibility to all objects in that schema. I belong to an APP_DBA_ROLE that has a lot of access associated.

Would I be able to modify my query to target a different view that might return a complete list of package objects? If not, is there a minimal access level that I can request that would give me the ability to see this package without also having to be granted access to execute it, too?

Comment: Do you have access to the `dba_objects` view?  That shows all objects in the database whether or not you have access to them.  But you'd generally need the `select any dictionary` privilege or the `select_catalog_role` role to be able to access the `dba_*` views.

Comment: @Justin Cave Thanks, Justin. That works for me but I'm writing a desktop client app where everyone will be connecting to the db with their own credentials, so over all, it is not a solution. Changing the permissions on specific options is probably not a solution either. There are too many objects with too many owners and making all these changes in prod would be difficult.

Comment: The issue is that for security reasons, Oracle's default is not to confirm to a user that an object exists unless that user has been granted some level of access to it.  The `select any dictionary` privilege and the `select_catalog_role` role give users permission to be aware of all the objects in the database.  If granting those permissions to all the users that you want to access the database via your app isn't realistic, could you grant them access to just the specific data dictionary views they need?  For example, you can grant access just to `sys.dba_objects`.

Comment: I believe you can grant `select_catalog_role` to `public` (or create a different role just for those people who should be able to see all objects, even those they have no privileges on). You wouldn't have to grant it individually to each user who uses the app.

Comment: I couldn't see objects of type PACKAGE_BODY in all_objects, but I could in dba_objects. Why the hell does "all_objects" return different stuff to "dba_objects". Why doesn't "all_objects" just mean all objects? I'm so sick to death of finding behaviours like this in Oracle. I hate everything they've ever created.

Comment: all system views are from the security perspective of the user by default. even ALL_OBJECTS, which shows all objects of all types, not objects that you don't have access to. DBAs have more rights, so you would expect to see everything. I just found it strange that I could get the code for an object that otherwise was not visible to me and wouldn't know that it even existed if looking at the ALL_OBJECTS view.